# Why won't my float code work?

Tags: css-float

I'm going crazy trying to figure out why this code isn't working to put these 2 divs side-by-side. Am I crazy? Is this an obvious fix? Please help! Thank you

```
  <div id="masth" align="right">
  <div id="mastleft">Creativene is a place for artists and art enthusiasts to come together to buy and sell art.<br>
  <br>
  Sign-up today!</div>

  <div id="mastright"><img src="images/masthead.png" width="50%" height="50%">
  </div>
  </div>


<style>
   #masth {
     background: #F0F0F0;
     border-radius: 50px;
     width:100%;
     padding: 30px;
    }

   #mastright {
     float: left;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a width to the `mastleft` div?

Answer (score 0):

Floated elements should be defined BEFORE the elements they're floating relative to, e.g.

```
<div>
    <div id="mastright">...</div>  <--- defined first
    <div id="mastleft"> ...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Div elements have an implicit new line attached to them.  If you want to elements to be on the same line, use `<span>...</span>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="masth" align="right">
  <div id="mastleft">Creativene is a place for artists and art enthusiasts to come together to buy and sell art.<br>
    <br>
    Sign-up today!</div>
  <div id="mastright"><img src="images/masthead.png" width="50%" height="50%"> </div>
</div>
<style>
   #masth {
     background: #F0F0F0;
     border-radius: 50px;
     width:450px;
     margin:0px auto;
     padding: 30px;
     overflow:hidden;
    }
    #mastleft{
        float:right;
        width: 50%;
        margin: 20px;
    }
   #mastright {
     float: right;
     width:150px;
     height:150px;
     background:red;
    }
</style>
```